# Workitem In Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I wanted to create a custom workitem in such a way that it passes through the specified states. Like it cannot go from the new state to the closed state with out passing through the active state. If such thing happens like it is modified directly from the new state to the closed state then it should through an error.
Can this procedure happen?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps supports the application of rules for work item state transitions, as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops. There's a fairly detailed example there.

Essentially, what you do is to create a rule for each state under the inherited process you create for your project, that limits where it can go from that state.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom rule to restrict transitioning from new to the closed directly. See below steps:

1,Organization settings-->Process under Boards--> Select the [Inherited Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) your project is using.

> Note: Agile, Basic, Scrum, and CMMI—which are locked from being changed. You can only add a custom rule in an inherited process. Please [create a inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops) if your project is not using inherited process.

[image]

2, Select the Work item type you want to restrict transitioning of states-->Rules-->New rule.

[image]

3, Create a new rule to [restrict transitioning from new to the closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#restrict-modification-of-closed-work-items)

[image]

See Document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) for more information.